# Using two directives on the same DOM element breaks the binding

Tags: angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<div addressbook loader-channel="addressbook" loader="loader.promise">
    <div loader-success="addressbook">
        <div contacts="{{ contacts }}" selected-contact="selectedContact">
```

Here, the main app is the `addressbook` directive.

The `loader` is another directive that runs on top. While data is being retrieved, it shows an ajax loader icon, and hides `loader-success` div. After the loader is done, the `loader-success` div is then shown and the loader icon is removed. A `promise` is used to control this.

My `contacts` directive just shows a list of contacts. If a user clicks on one, then `selectedContact` is changed and the main app should notice this. As a result, the `contacts` is passed as a one-way binding, and `selectedContact` is passed as a two-way binding.

Here are the directives of the two:

```
app.directive('addressbook', function($q, $resource)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/file',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.loader          = $q.defer();
            scope.contacts        = null;
            scope.selectedContact = null;

            $resource('users').query(function(response) {
                scope.contacts = response;
                scope.loader.resolve();
            });

            scope.$watch('selectedContact', function(contact) {
                if (! contact) return;

                // Now contact is changed. Show this contact
                // But this does not work
            });
        }
    }
});

app.directive('contacts', function($q, $resource)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            contacts        : '@',
            selectedContact : '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'path/to/other/file',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            attrs.$observe('contacts', function(contacts) {
                if ( ! contacts) return;

                scope.contacts = angular.fromJson(contacts);
            });

            // This is called through ng-click
            scope.select = function(contact) {
                scope.selectedContact = contact;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The `$watch` is not triggered. If I remove `loader` attributes, then it IS triggered. What are my options?

Comment: Any errors are multiple directives trying to make an isolated scope on the same element.

Comment: how is the loader directive hiding and showing things? is it just with a `display: none` or is it actively removing and adding things to the DOM?

Comment: @user2943490, it hides and shows the element. It doesn't add/remove things from the DOM.